# Replacing air with nitrogen in a drum.

Tags: home-experiment

I have a 55 gallon drum half ful of liquid. I would like to put a "blanket" of nitrogen over the liquid. How can I replace the air in the drum with nitrogen?

Comment: Why not use caron dioxide? Much easier.

Comment: Is your liquid hazardous in any way?

Comment: No but if it works we might look at using it for other applications. Do you foresee any safety concerns? I was trying to avoid safety issues by using Nitrogen.

Comment: Just curious about how you were using it to double check that you're being safe :) and to see if there are specialized parts available.  If you check safety equipment suppliers, you can find pumps and gas regulators for drums.